# nothing is happening when ic_drawer icon is clicked

Tags: android

Though I have set
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
the navigation pane does not show up when I touch on the navigation icon ic_drawer.

Below is the code:
    package com.happyshare;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.happyshare.utilities.RequestTask;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";
    SharedPreferences settings = null;
    String strUserName = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onCreate method");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        if(!isLoggedIn()){
            InitializeUI();

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            tv.setText("Hello " + settings.getString("UserName", "Guys"));
        }

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }

        final Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click   
                 new RequestTask().execute("http://api.brfares.com/querysimple?orig=LDS&dest=OXF");

                //Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);

                // currentContext.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);

                //PresentActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);


            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onCreateOptionsMenu method");
        MenuInflater mif = getMenuInflater();
        //mif.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        mif.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onOptionsItemSelected method");
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.bookings_icon:
                facebookLoginDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.person_icon:
                facebookLoginDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.messages_icon:
                facebookLoginDialog();
                break;
            default:
                ;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside isLoggedIn method");
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return (session != null && session.isOpened());
    }

    private void facebookLoginDialog(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside facebookLoginDialog method");

        if(!isLoggedIn()){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("This function requires Happyshare login.")
            .setMessage("Do you want to continue?")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 } })
            .setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    facebookLogin();
                }
            }).show();
        }

    }

    private void facebookLogoutDialog(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside facebookLogoutDialog method");

        if(isLoggedIn()){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Are you sure you want to log out.")
            .setMessage("Do you want to continue?")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 } })
            .setPositiveButton("Log Out", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "**********Before if******************");
                    Facebook fb = new Facebook(getResources().getString(R.string.app_id));
                    Log.d(TAG, "------------------0--------------------");
                    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                    Log.d(TAG, "------------------1--------------------");
                    session.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "------------------2--------------------");
                    //try {
                         //should be called on separate thread
                         //fb.logout(getApplicationContext());
                         MainActivity.this.finish();
                         finish();
                         Log.d(TAG, "Starting Intent for logging out.");
                         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogoutActivity.class));
                     /*} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                         Log.e(TAG, "Got MalformedURLException::"+e.getMessage());
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         Log.e(TAG, "Got IOException::"+e.getMessage());
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }*/
                }
            }).show();
        }
    }

    private void facebookLogin(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside facebookLogin method");

        //start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside call method");
            if (session.isOpened()){

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null){

                        strUserName = user.getName();
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("UserName", strUserName);

                        editor.commit();

                        // sets username
                        TextView user_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
                        user_name.setText("Hello " + strUserName);

                        // sets the facebook verified image here
                        ImageView profileVerifiedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_verified);
                        profileVerifiedImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook_verified);

                        // sets the phone verified image here
                        ImageView phoneVerifiedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_verified);
                        phoneVerifiedImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_not_verified);

                        // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                        /*String userID = null;
                        userID = user.getId();
                        Log.i(TAG, "The userid is::"+userID);
                        String strImageURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large";
                        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);
                        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) new DownloadImageTask().doInBackground(strImageURL);
                        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);*/

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
}

    /*private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String strURL = null;
            try {
                strURL = params[0].toString();
                Log.i(TAG, "Image URL is::"+strURL);
                URL imageURL = new URL(strURL);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("TAG", "*************Error in retrieving the profile image**************");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onActivityResult method");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onPrepareOptionsMenu method");
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside selectItem method");
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        Log.d(TAG,"Inside select item::"+position);
        switch(position){
            case 0 : 
                facebookLoginDialog();
                break;
            case 1 : 
                facebookLoginDialog();
                break;
            case 2 : 
                facebookLoginDialog();
                break;
            case 3 : 
                facebookLoginDialog();
                break;
            case 6 : 
                facebookLogoutDialog();
                break;
            default:
                ;
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside setTitle method");
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onPostCreate method");
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Inside onConfigurationChanged method");
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
     */
    public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public PlanetFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside onCreateView method");
            View rootView = null;
            /*View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                            "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            ImageView imageViewFragment = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageViewFragment.setImageResource(imageId);
            //imageViewFragment.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            getActivity().setTitle(planet);
            */            
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    // used in onCreate() and onConfigurationChanged() to set up the UI elements
    public void InitializeUI()
    {

        // sets the facebook verified image here
        ImageView profileVerifiedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profile_verified);
        profileVerifiedImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.facebook_verified);

        // sets the phone verified image here
        ImageView phoneVerifiedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.phone_verified);
        phoneVerifiedImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.phone_not_verified);

    }

}
```

Comment: you are extending activity but you should extend ActionBarActivity

Comment: Its my main activity. How can I extend ActionBarActivity. Please be bit elaborate.

Comment: change public class *MainActivity extends Activity*  to *public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity*

Comment: @Chalpat Did you resolved it?

Comment: no its not solved yet. I know I can change with the suggestion given above, but it does not seem correct to me.

Comment: I think the suggestion seems to be valid but hell lot of compilation issues when I am trying to change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was new to Android development. There is a option right at the beginning given by ADT to create project in your way. Just do not blindly create the project select correct activity, like I now selected with Navigation Drawer Activity and it has all built in features.

Comment: So, you did managed to solve your issue, right?